# How to declare a sub-function in which are the variables for the main-function are declared and connect them

Tags: javascript

I want to declare a sub-function for storing important variables for the main function to save the readability of the main-funciton. The first code beneath is the main-function and the second is the sub-function.

```
function calci() {

    VarOfElements(connection) ;

    
    const condExceededPersons = inp2 > 4;
    const condPersonsCosts = persons === 4 && km > 0;
    const condNonePersonsCosts = persons < 4 || inp2 != null;

    if (condExceededPersons) {
        output.innerHTML = "Only four persons can drive with you!";
    } else if (condPersonsCosts) {
        var personsExpenses = 5;
    } else if (condNonePersonsCosts) {
        personsExpenses = 0;
    }
    const noInput = inp1 != null;
    if (noInput) {
        output.innerHTML = "Please enter a distance";
    }
    const conditionSevenO = km <= 7 && km > 0;
    const overSevenOeq = km > 7 && km > 0;

    if (conditionSevenO) {
        y = 3.9
        var wholeExpenses = routePrice * km + y + personsExpenses;
        output.innerHTML = "You have to pay " + wholeExpenses.toFixed(2) + "€";
    } else if (overSevenOeq) {
        y = 3.9
        let sevenLess = km - 7;
        let overSevenRoute = 1.65;
        let overSeven = sevenLess * overSevenRoute;
        let seventhExpenses = 16.10;
        wholeExpenses = y + seventhExpenses + overSeven + personsExpenses;
        output.innerHTML = "You have to pay " + wholeExpenses.toFixed(2) + "€";

    }
}
```

```
function VarOfElements(connection) {
    var y;
    var routePrice = 2.3;
    inp1 = document.getElementById('input-box1');
    inp2 = document.getElementById('input-box2');
    var km = parseInt(document.getElementById('input-box1').value);
    var persons = parseInt(document.getElementById('input-box2').value);
    output = document.getElementById('output-box');
    }
```

Comment: What problem are you having? Just nest the sub function inside the main function.

Comment: You should declare the variables inside the main function.

Comment: What is the `connection` parameter for? You never use it in the sub-function.

Comment: It is not working this way, I tried

Comment: I wanted to return it with connection but this was the wrong way

Comment: So you have the sub function return the info needed. Typically you return an object.  How you access it from the object is up to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is for the sub-function to return an object containing all the values. You can then assign this to variables in the main function.

In the code below I use destructuring to extract the values from the object.

`inp1` and `inp2` will never be `null`. They're DOM elements, not the values. And `parseInt()` returns `NaN` when the input is empty, not `null`, so you use `isNaN()` to test it. You need to test the variables that contain the values.

After you display an error message in `output.innerHTML` you should return from the function so you don't continue into the calculation code.

```js
function calci() {

  const {routePrice, km, persons, output} = VarOfElements();

  const condExceededPersons = persons > 4;
  const condPersonsCosts = persons === 4 && km > 0;
  const condNonePersonsCosts = persons < 4 || !isNaN(persons);

  if (condExceededPersons) {
    output.innerHTML = "Only four persons can drive with you!";
    return;
  } else if (condPersonsCosts) {
    var personsExpenses = 5;
  } else if (condNonePersonsCosts) {
    personsExpenses = 0;
  }
  const noInput = isNaN(km);
  if (noInput) {
    output.innerHTML = "Please enter a distance";
    return;
  }
  const conditionSevenO = km <= 7 && km > 0;
  const overSevenOeq = km > 7 && km > 0;

  if (conditionSevenO) {
    y = 3.9
    var wholeExpenses = routePrice * km + y + personsExpenses;
    output.innerHTML = "You have to pay " + wholeExpenses.toFixed(2) + "€";
  } else if (overSevenOeq) {
    y = 3.9
    let sevenLess = km - 7;
    let overSevenRoute = 1.65;
    let overSeven = sevenLess * overSevenRoute;
    let seventhExpenses = 16.10;
    wholeExpenses = y + seventhExpenses + overSeven + personsExpenses;
    output.innerHTML = "You have to pay " + wholeExpenses.toFixed(2) + "€";
  }
}

function VarOfElements() {
  const routePrice = 2.3;
  const inp1 = document.getElementById('input-box1');
  const inp2 = document.getElementById('input-box2');
  const km = parseInt(inp1.value);
  const persons = parseInt(inp2.value);
  const output = document.getElementById('output-box');
  return {routePrice, km, persons, output};
}
```

```html
Distance: <input id="input-box1">
<br>
Number of passengers: <input id="input-box2">
<br>
<button onclick="calci()">Calculate price</button>
<br>
Price:
<span id="output-box"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working. But your forget to include "inp1" and "inp2" in the return statement. So this kind of solution is called destructuring, right?

Comment: I updated the answer. You shouldn't be using `inp1` and `inp2` in the main function, and you were using them wrong.

Comment: Thank you. So is that the reason why the string "Only four persons can drive with you!" is not displayed even though the value of the var "persons" is higher than four like I determined in the var "condExceededPersons" or in the first if-query respectively?

Comment: No, that should work since I changed it to `persons > 4`

Comment: It is not working, do you have an idea why? I executed the code several times in the way that the if-query is going to be true but it is still not displaying the associated string

Comment: You don't exit from the function when you display an error message. So it performs the calculation anyway and overwrites the error message.

Comment: function createSpaceforVar(a) {

    a = output.innerHTML = "Only four persons can drive with you!";
    function warnings(a) {
    return a;
    }
    const result = warnings(a);
    return result;
} Is this okay when I stop the function with a sub function in which is a return statement and provide the possibility to execute the string

Comment: I already edited the answer to show how to do it.

Comment: Because you declared const condNonePersonsCosts = persons < 4 || !isNaN(persons); or the part with Persons !isNaN the function can only calculate km when persons has a value like 0 or a other number but when I using my old method so that if persons = null what you complained about it is working even when persons is null. Why is that so ?

Comment: Your original code has `inp2 != null`. That was incorrect since it wasn't checking the value, it was checking whether the element exists. The correct code to check that the value is valid is `!isNaN(persons)`. `persons` can never be `null`, `parseInt()` always returns either an integer or `NaN`.